# These two questions regarding video games

Tags: practical-islam, shirk, game

I have some questions regarding video games. Please answer these questions because it's hard to find fatwas about video games. I know that playing games are not recommended. However I just want to know some answers.

### Game 1

I play a card video game that has some names like "revelation" or "know the fate" these card just allow you to see your opponent's card. So playing such game is shirk? If it is, will I able to play that game not using those names of card but play with other normal cards? Just please tell me whether it's shirk or not

### Game 2

Another game that has water fountain. I have put some points in that fountain and it gives me coins. I don't know if it's wishing or not. No more than that. Is this action a shirk, even though it's fictional? Please answer

Comment: Does games are nothing but some small shrik, you have to stay away from because varely they are all distraction from shaytan

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum

These are just games and if you have wrong feeling about them then just leave it

ALLAH HAFIZ